# When resizing the window the elements jump around

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

When using a none maximised window and resizing horizontally the elements on the top bar jump around. First when the right hand "hamburger" logo is clipped the elements jump around slightly. Then when the current user link is covered the search bar extends to the width of the page and the text gets smaller.

See the following:

[image: Window resizing]

I have produced this on Windows 10 IE 11 and Chrome 56.

Comment: That would be to account for the lack of space. Depending on the browser width, the nav bar will be displayed differently. I don't really agree with that because the rest of the site is not responsive, so the nav bar shouldn't be, but meh.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Just curious: Does having a mix of responsive and non-responsive cause particular problems or do you not like it just because it's weird? Or maybe it sets incorrect expectations for the user?

Comment: I do wonder if this means they're moving toward making the entire site responsive.

Comment: @BSMP it won't cause any problems per se. It just doesn't sit right with me because it gives me an expectation that the rest of the site should be responsive. As for whether they're moving toward making the entire site responsive, it would be a good idea, but the format doesn't really allow for it.